# jquery go to previous parent element

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make a form by steps and when i'm on the 3 step and try to go to the previous step(2) it goes right to the first step, im using the next() and prev(), the code is in the fiddle.

Thanks for the help

http://fiddle.jshell.net/zo9gnk8c/3/

Comment: because your anchor tag is refreshing the page

Comment: Thank you that does the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7e925ebp/)

You have to suppress the anchor click

```
$("button").click(function(){
    if($(this).parent().next("fieldset").length > 0){
        $(this).parent().toggle();
        $(this).parent().next().toggle();
    }
});
$(".goBack").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Added this new line
    if($(this).parent().prev("fieldset").length > 0){
        $(this).parent().toggle();  
        $(this).parent().prev("fieldset").toggle();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

set href to `#` for anchor tags to prevent page refresh:

```
<a href="#" class="goBack">Previous</a>
```

**[Working Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4jdzL2aa/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `return:false;` or `e.preventDefault()` at the end of your code

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/zo9gnk8c/4/

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).parent().next("fieldset").length > 0) {
            $(this).parent().toggle();
            $(this).parent().next().toggle();
        }
        return false
    });
    $(".goBack").click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).parent().prev("fieldset").length > 0) {
            $(this).parent().toggle();
            $(this).parent().prev("fieldset").toggle();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you click on the goback link, it reloads the page as it is an `<a>` tag with a blank href. In order to stop the default behaviour add an event to your goback click function and stop the default action

```
$(".goback").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // Do something - your logic
});
```